# Object control while creating a new one with constructor

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I  have a simple bank account class. I don't want to create an object if the user's age is younger than 18.

So I tried to create a class like this. But It doesn't work. Can I do something like what I want in Object-Oriented programming?

```
public class BankAccount {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private  int age;
    private  double balance;
    private String accNumber;

    public BankAccount(String name, String id, int age, double balance, String accNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accNumber = accNumber;
        if (age<18){
            System.out.println("You can not create a bank account If You're younger than 18 years old");
            return;
     }
}
```

Comment: You should throw an exception instead of returning. An `InvalidArgumentException` should be fine for the purpose of the exercise. Even better, you could define a custom exception to represent the particular case (e.g. `UnderageUserException`).

Comment: You need to throw an exception to "cancel" execution of the constructor, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`. However, a better design might use a factory method that checks the constraints before constructing the instance. When throwing the exception from the constructor you should at least do that as early as possible to avoid unwanted side effects that might result from accessing data or methods before throwing the exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we stop the run of a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250646/can-we-stop-the-run-of-a-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some hints in the comments, but I'll post my answer here. This is only a suggested way of doing it, but there could be other approaches, depending on how you want to design your code.

You could use a static factory method that will create your object only if the age is greater than or equal to 18. Example:

```
public class BankAccount {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int age;
    private double balance;
    private String accNumber;

    // Notice the private constructor. This class can be instantiated only by call the static method #from
    private BankAccount(String name, String id, int age, double balance, String accNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.age = age;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accNumber = accNumber;
    }

    public static BankAccount from(String name, String id, int age, double balance, String accNumber) {
        if (age < 18) {
            return null;
        }

        return new BankAccount(name, id, age, balance, accNumber);
    }

}
```

And you would create your BankAccount as:

```
// This will be null, because age < 18
BankAccount bankAccount = BankAccount.from("name", "id", 1, 0, "accNumber");

// This will be an actual object
BankAccount bankAccount = BankAccount.from("name", "id", 20, 0, "accNumber");
```